# Update values in a column based on a comparison of two other tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-function

In postgres I have 3 tables that are joined by two keys:

Key A joins tables 1 and 2, is not unique in table 1, is unique in table 2 and does not exist in table 3

Key B joins tables 2 and 3 does not exist in table 1 and is unique in tables 2 and 3.

---

I am looking to update a column in table 3 that should hold a count of records in table 1 (all values in that column are 0).

Table_1

```
+-----+
| Key |
+-----+
| A1  |
| A1  |
| A1  |
| A2  |
| A2  |
| A3  |
| A3  |
+-----+
```

Table_2

```
+-------+-------+
| Key_A | Key_B |
+-------+-------+
| A1    | B1    |
| A2    | B2    |
| A3    | B3    |
+-------+-------+
```

Table_3 (desired result)

```
+-------+--------+
| Key_B | Count  |
+-------+--------+
| B1    |      3 |
| B2    |      2 |
| B3    |      2 |
+-------+--------+
```

---

I'm stuck at the update command (not familiar enough with them yet), I've got the counts I need with:

```
Select Table_3.Key_B, count(Table_1.*)
from Table_1
Join Table_2 on Table_1.Key_A = Table_2.Key_A
Join Table_3 on Table_2.Key_B = Table 3.Key_B
Group by 1
```

I'm just not quite sure how to update the the records in table 3 with the right counts. I think I might need a function but I'm not sure.  Is this on the right track?

```
Create or replace function my_funct
  returns varchar as
$body$
Declare
      r         record
begin
      select key_B from Table_3 into r;

      update Table_3
      set count = ( 
                   select count(*) 
                   from table_1
                   Join Table_2 on Table_1.Key_A = Table_2.Key_A
                   Join Table_3 on Table_2.Key_B = Table 3.Key_B
                   Where key_B = r
                   );  
end
$body$
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avoid an expensive correlated subquery:

```
update t3
set c = t.c
from (
    select t2.b, count(*) as c
    from t1 join t2 on t1.a = t2.a
    group by 1
) t
where t3.b = t.b
;
table t3;
 b | c 
---+---
 1 | 3
 2 | 2
 3 | 2
```

As I understand `key_B` in `table_2` is a foreign key to `table_3` so it is not necessary to join `table_3` in the `from` clause.

```
create table t2 (a int primary key, b int unique);
create table t1 (a int references t2);
create table t3 (b int unique references t2, c int);

insert into t2 (a, b) values (1,1),(2,2),(3,3);
insert into t1 (a) values (1),(1),(1),(2),(2),(3),(3);
insert into t3 (b) values (1),(2),(3);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a *correlation* condition in the subquery:

```
 update Table_3
      set count = (select count(*) 
                   from table_1 t1 join
                        table_2 t2
                        on t1.Key_A = t2.Key_A
                   where t2.Key_B = Table_3.Key_B
                  );
```

There reference for `Table_3` is from the outer query.

Actually, you don't even need the `join` assuming there is a proper foreign key relationship between `Table_1` and `Table_2` and `Table_1` does not have duplicates:

```
 update Table_3
      set count = (select count(*) 
                   from table_2 t2
                   where t2.Key_B = Table_3.Key_B
                  );
```

After reviewing the question, I realize this is not the case, but I offer the solution anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE #table3 SET _Count = Cnt FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) Cnt,#table1.Key_A,Key_B  KeyB FROM #table1 JOIN #table2 ON #table1.Key_A = #table2.Key_A GROUP BY #table1.Key_A,Key_B ) A WHERE KeyB = Key_B
```